# How to map arrays using with_index in ruby ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, mapping

I've the following code for mapping the n-D array. If the input are `[[C, "O"], [C, "O"], [C, "#"], [C]]` the output is `"COCOC#C"` . I want the output to be `C(O)COC#C` this is the when there are two elements in first array the 2nd element should be in brackets. I've used the following code, I just couldn't implement the use of with_index function.

```
def format2smi
  # return a Smiles compliant chemical name as a string

  map do |element|
    format_step(element)
  end.join('')    #.join(')')

end # format2smi

protected

def format_step(e)
  e.map.with_index do |x,i|

    if x.is_a?(Array)
```

x="("+x[1]+")"

```
"(#{ format_step(x) })" # calling the same function
    else  
      x.to_s # convert to string and return
    end
  end.join('')   #gsub("", "(").gsub("", ")") # map returns an array of strings, join
end
```

Comment: I am not sure if you need to use `with_index` from your question and the code you have shared. Your code would function the same if you removed the call to `with_index` (and also removed the named index `i` from your declared iteration vars) since you are not using the index `i` in your code. If I am missing something can you please clarify your question a bit?

Comment: @DRSE Thanks a lot, I've solved the issue, and posted the answer as well. Thanks though :)

Comment: @sawa, it's a computer language developed by Dennis Richie in the early 1970's. It is credited with saving countless thousands of FORTRAN programmers from going mad.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the brackets only on the first element, it's enough to just do:

```
array = [['C', 'O'], ['C', 'O'], ['C', '#'], ['C']]

array.first[1] = "(#{array.first[1]})" if array.first.size == 2
array.join # => "C(O)COC#C"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue. So stupid of me. :/

```
 def format_step(e)
  e.map.with_index do |x,i|

    if x.is_a?(Array)
      "(#{ format_step(x) })" # calling the same function
    else  
      if i ==0
        x.to_s
      else
       "("+x.to_s+")"
      end
      # convert to string and return
    end
  end.join('')
end
```